# Why Media Queries is not working on live server but working in local pc?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, media-queries

I have a page [here](http://www.demo.yogihosting.com/html/CSS-Media-Queries/) which shows another page inside an iframe. The page also has some icons on the top bar which changes the width of the iframe on clicking. These icons actually shows responsive nature of the page.

So when clicking on the mobile icon (portrait) the jquery changes the width of iframe to 320 px. So the other page (which iframe shows) should show the work of media queries.

The page which iframe contains is responsive in nature (through media queries in the css).

Unfortunately this is working only on local pc but on live server it is not working. Why? please help.

Comment: Let me check: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XMHfcRtKaks/VcqdoF68tiI/AAAAAAAABCA/mRONtzlpgCE/s1600/tumblr_mqs90xiuRU1r2kb4qo1_500.gif

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude i just solved the problem. The problem was that old style sheet was coming from cloudflare cache so on removing the cache from cloudflare account, it solved my problem.

Comment: Well, next time you ask something try to share the relevant code or the relevant mounted systems to allow us to know what is happening on your issue. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Good luck!